# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator, move to another screen button

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a button that will take me from one screen to another. Second one is titled "Note taking screen", sadly when I did it this way as below I get the following error: "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator."

I've tried to follow:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Any ideas what I did wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Note extends StatelessWidget {
  const Note({super.key});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Note taking screen")),
          body: Container(),
        );
      }
    }
```

ssss

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:notepad/screens/Note.dart';

 class TextFieldExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldExampleApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Note()));
            }),
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: TextField(
            //No const because it changes
            onChanged: (String value) {
              if (value == '13') {
                print("Right number entered");
              }
            },
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: ListOfNotes(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const TextFieldExampleApp());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you've structured your widget tree.

You should return a `MaterialApp` widget as the root widget of your app. This way, the Navigator will be available in the widget tree. Also, remove the `MaterialApp` from the `TextFieldExampleApp`.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: const TextFieldExampleApp()));
```

```
class TextFieldExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldExampleApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Note()));
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: TextField(
          //No const because it changes
          onChanged: (String value) {
            if (value == '13') {
              print("Right number entered");
            }
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('List OF notes'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in Material Widget. You are using `context` without `Material Widget`. Because Navigation flow created from `Material Widget`.

Remove `Material widget` inside the `TextFieldExampleApp`. And Wrap `TextFieldExampleApp`.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: const TextFieldExampleApp())); <====== Added MaterialApp here.
```

TextFieldExampleApp code

```
class TextFieldExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldExampleApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(          <===========   Remove MaterialApp From Here
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Note()));
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: TextField(
          //No const because it changes
          onChanged: (String value) {
            if (value == '13') {
              print("Right number entered");
            }
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('List OF notes'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```